# Disable Spring's implicit method dependency injection

Tags: java, spring, dependency-injection, struts2

I'm currently using Struts to develop an app, and the hello world page worked just fine until I made it extend `ActionSupport` to get access to i18n features. Upon doing this, the action started always returning `input` as the result string. This is obviously unexpected as there is no validation done at the moment. After debugging, I noticed that Spring decided to inject a field error map, so validation always sees something, causing the unexpected return value.

[image: injection parameter]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8W8hu.png)

Here is the stack trace:

```
Daemon Thread [http-0.0.0.0-8080-2] (Suspended (breakpoint at line 79 in ActionSupport))    
Index(ActionSupport).setFieldErrors(Map<String,List<String>>) line: 79  
NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Method, Object, Object[]) line: not available [native method]  
NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: not available   
DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Object, Object[]) line: not available   
Method.invoke(Object, Object...) line: not available    
BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(BeanWrapperImpl$PropertyTokenHolder, PropertyValue) line: 1134 
BeanWrapperImpl.setPropertyValue(PropertyValue) line: 903   
BeanWrapperImpl(AbstractPropertyAccessor).setPropertyValues(PropertyValues, boolean, boolean) line: 75  
BeanWrapperImpl(AbstractPropertyAccessor).setPropertyValues(PropertyValues) line: 57    
DefaultListableBeanFactory(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory).applyPropertyValues(String, BeanDefinition, BeanWrapper, PropertyValues) line: 1450  
DefaultListableBeanFactory(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory).populateBean(String, RootBeanDefinition, BeanWrapper) line: 1158 
DefaultListableBeanFactory(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory).autowireBeanProperties(Object, int, boolean) line: 376   
StrutsSpringObjectFactory(SpringObjectFactory).autoWireBean(Object, AutowireCapableBeanFactory) line: 218   
StrutsSpringObjectFactory(SpringObjectFactory).buildBean(Class, Map<String,Object>) line: 198   
StrutsSpringObjectFactory(SpringObjectFactory).buildBean(String, Map<String,Object>, boolean) line: 164 
StrutsSpringObjectFactory(ObjectFactory).buildBean(String, Map<String,Object>) line: 178    
DefaultActionFactory.buildAction(String, String, ActionConfig, Map<String,Object>) line: 22 
StrutsSpringObjectFactory(ObjectFactory).buildAction(String, String, ActionConfig, Map<String,Object>) line: 148    
DefaultActionInvocation.createAction(Map<String,Object>) line: 295  
DefaultActionInvocation.init(ActionProxy) line: 395 
StrutsActionProxy(DefaultActionProxy).prepare() line: 194   
StrutsActionProxy.prepare() line: 63    
StrutsActionProxyFactory.createActionProxy(ActionInvocation, String, String, String, boolean, boolean) line: 37 
StrutsActionProxyFactory(DefaultActionProxyFactory).createActionProxy(String, String, String, Map<String,Object>, boolean, boolean) line: 58    
Dispatcher.serviceAction(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, ActionMapping) line: 554  
ExecuteOperations.executeAction(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, ActionMapping) line: 81    
StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 99   
ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 235  
ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 206  
OpenSessionInViewFilter.doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest, HttpServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 232    
OpenSessionInViewFilter(OncePerRequestFilter).doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 106  
ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 235  
ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 206  
ReplyHeaderFilter.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain) line: 96   
ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 235  
ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse) line: 206  
StandardWrapperValve.invoke(Request, Response) line: 230    
StandardContextValve.invoke(Request, Response) line: 175    
SecurityAssociationValve.invoke(Request, Response) line: 182    
JaccContextValve.invoke(Request, Response) line: 84 
StandardHostValve.invoke(Request, Response) line: 127   
ErrorReportValve.invoke(Request, Response) line: 102    
CachedConnectionValve.invoke(Request, Response) line: 157   
StandardEngineValve.invoke(Request, Response) line: 109 
CoyoteAdapter.service(Request, Response) line: 262  
Http11Processor.process(Socket) line: 844   
Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Socket) line: 583    
JIoEndpoint$Worker.run() line: 446  
Thread.run() line: not available
```

This is basically all that the class contains:

```
public class Index extends ActionSupport implements UserAware
{
    private User user;


    @Override
    public String execute()
    {
        System.out.println("this doesn't print out");
        return "SUCCESS";
    }

    @Override
    public void setUser(User user)
    {
        this.user = user;
    }

    public User getUser()
    {
        return user;
    }
}
```

I'm only using the `@Autowired` annotated property injection, so I'd like to disable the method injection to fix this issue. That is of course if that is the problem. I could have misinterpreted the symptoms.

#### Versions

- Spring 3.2.9
- Struts 2.3.24

Comment: We'll need more information, like versions, and whether or not you have something called `errorMap` somewhere in your Spring classes. It's not doing this randomly on its own.

Comment: Updated question with software versions. I am not using anything named `errorMap` (grep'ed all source files).

Comment: Can you create a minimal working example on gitHub? I haven't seen this issue, nor can I think of any reasons it might happen accidentally unless there's something explicit happening somewhere. Also, is this occurring after an S2 upgrade?

Comment: I'll try to create a minimal example but might take some time. This is an issue with a new project, not an upgrade so everything is fresh.

Comment: I figured out the issue, take a look at my answer. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to fix this by changing the autowire type to `none` in the `struts.xml` file. I initially set it to `type` because I thought that `@Autowire` injection wouldn't work otherwise. I guess I was wrong since those injections still work.

```
<constant name="struts.objectFactory.spring.autoWire" value="type" />
```

to

```
<constant name="struts.objectFactory.spring.autoWire" value="none" />
```

Thanks to all participants for helping.

Comment: Actually there isn't such value as `none` for `struts.objectFactory.spring.autoWire`. You can just remove this constant.

Answer (score 0):

Struts and Spring does not go well together by default, You need to add struts2-spring-plugin-x.y.z.jar in your WEB-INF/lib from your struts lib directory. and configure it properly in web.xml, refer this http://www.tutorialspoint.com/struts_2/struts_spring.htm

Comment: I already have the plugin as evidenced by `StrutsSpringObjectFactory` in the stack.

Comment: Yes that's correct, can you show where have you used @Autowired annotation

Comment: I'm not using it here. Spring is automatically injecting something into a class in the Struts library that I am extending.

Comment: also are you using struts 2 as per the logs it seems you are using different version. try the versions from  http://www.mkyong.com/struts/struts-spring-integration-example/ also use spring documentation for configuring struts 2 actions http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.5.RELEASE/reference/web-integration.html#struts (use spring's ActionSupport instead of struts ActionSupport)

Comment: @amitmahajan There aren't any Spring `ActionSupport` classes for Struts 2.

Comment: Hi Dave, i see this is there as per the above documentation and i feel this is the exact problem here [17.4 Apache Struts 1.x and 2.x]

Answer (score 0):

This happens due to `ActionSupport` implements all interfaces required for validation, like [`Validatable`](http://struts.apache.org/maven/xwork-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/Validateable.html) and [`ValidationAware`](http://struts.apache.org/maven/xwork-core/apidocs/com/opensymphony/xwork2/ValidationAware.html).

> `ValidationAware` classes can accept `Action` (class level) or field level error messages. Action level messages are kept in a `Collection`. Field level error messages are kept in a `Map` from `String` field name to a `List` of field error messages.

The last one is more specific to injection of errors but it's not a Spring job (Spring uses its object factory to build the action and inject *its* dependencies), it's a Struts job to support the action with field errors and action errors, and it's well done with the [`validation`](http://struts.apache.org/docs/validation-interceptor.html) interceptor.

> This interceptor runs the action through the standard validation framework, which in turn checks the action against any validation rules (found in files such as `ActionClass-validation.xml`) and adds field-level and action-level error messages (provided that the action implements `com.opensymphony.xwork2.ValidationAware`).

The `validation` interceptor is included in the `defaultStack` which is used by default in any action. If the action doesn't need the validation capabilities you can remove this interceptor from the stack by creating a new stack, or overriding the action config. If the validation is provided to other methods, then you can exclude some methods from the interceptor or apply a `@SkipValidation` annotation. That would disable the validation from the method of the action.

Comment: The map that is injected happens at Action instantiation, long before the validator kicks in. That said, the `@SkipValidation` seems like an ok way to workaround the issue if I fail to solve it.

Comment: Seems like you have something in application context autowiring it in the action.